# Streamsets stream selector

Tags: conditional-statements, streamsets

I have a queue in JSON format in RabbitMQ and I would like to get some data that fix some conditions in StreamSets (using stream selector) and then save in a new database (JDBC Producer) a certain value. How do I write the specific value after the conditions and send to de database?

[image: StreamSets pipeline]

Comment: You should try yourself first and ask specific questions here. Please check [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: You can get specific help on the StreamSets Google Group or Slack channel - links from the StreamSets community page at https://streamsets.com/community/

Answer (score 1):

From your pipeline diagram, it looks like you're trying to set the field values you need for the database. You should be able to do this in the JDBC Producer itself - configure the **Field to Column Mapping**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use default streamsets component named **Expression evaluator** for it.
You add or move any fields with it.

Link to the documentation:
[streamsets expression evaluator](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/3.4.1/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Processors/Expression.html)